# UITableViewCell subclass: in what delegate method is it appropriate to do changes to the cells layer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a subclass of UITableViewCell where I set up the look/layout of my cell. Now I also want to add rounded corners to the cell by calling setCornerRadius on the cells layer. I know I can set it from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: when creating the cell, like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    ...

    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
    [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
}
```

However, I want to keep all the look/layout related code inside the subclass itself, so my question is:

**In what delegate method in my UITableViewCell subclass is it appropriate to do changes to the cells layer?**

Comment: Why you don't set "cornerRadius" in MyCell.m in -init or smth like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your cell is loaded from a nib, add the code to the `initWithCoder:` method. If you create it using `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` add it there. Basically, add it to the appropriate `init` method of your cell subclass.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't realize I was setting the corner radius inside initWithStyle when I was in fact loading it from a nib file - that's why I thought I had to set it in some secret delegate method or something. Your answer made me realize my mistake (and now I feel a bit stupid :S). Thanks!